# Can I recharge a Canaith Mandolin in Avernus?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

I just got a Canaith Mandolin while being in Avernus and there is something in the description that I would like to clarify.

If I understand well, in Avernus, there isn't any dawn. No sunrise.

Does that mean that if I stay in Avernus I won't be able to recharge my Canaith Mandolin spells ?

The description says

> A bard playing a Canaith mandolin could invoke the spells [...] each once a day, until the instrument recharged its magic at the next dawn.

Comment: Unless there is something special about Avernus that would affect the recharge aside from the dawn issue (and I don't know of any such detail), this looks to be a duplicate of [Do magic items replenish at dawn even if, in your current place, there is no such thing as dawn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125364), so I've closed it as such. If I've missed something feel free to point it out as always.